# What is the quickest way to get stable cloth-like deformation where nothing falls due to gravity or perpetually wobbles insanely?

Tags: animation, physics

No matter what setup I have, no matter how many times I try to do it whether with gravity or with some force that points up to counteract gravity, it never seems to completely work.

I want to just get the simplest case down first, generally I build animations in stages with deformation being one of the last. Suppose I just have two characters with an average armatures they're rigged to. How do I make it so that when one character punches another, their skin deforms from the fist of the other, but so that the fist part of the first character doesn't deform that much since that part is rigid? Is cloth physics even the right physics for this?

And is there a way to reduce the render time on this?

Comment: Do you just want to have it deformed like a draped cloth, but not have it still dynamically active?  If so, select the "cloth", go to the modify panel, and with the time line on a frame where the cloth looks good, click on Apply, then it's frozen in that position.

Comment: Well there wouldn't be much animation to render if it was frozen. It should be adaptive with the animation, like the further the first goes, the more they deform, then as their fist veers away, it undeforms.

Comment: Then you could freeze the cloth animation, and afterwards make it into a Soft Body with Collision active also.The fist can be a Passive Rigid Body. with Collision active. I haven't done simulations much in Blender, and am not sure you need Collision turned on, but with those settings, it just worked for me - animated a sphere to "punch" the cloth object which bulged inwards and deformed in a cloth like manner.